# Prime numbers from random samples in R

Tags: r

I wrote the following code trying to find all the prime numbers from a random generated data set. sadly it seems something went wrong, could anybody help me.

```
set.seed(20171106)
n <- 10000
num <- sample(1:100000,n,replace=TRUE)
findPrime <- function(x){
apple<-c()
n<-length(x)
for(i in n){
    if(any(x[i]%%(1:(x[i]-1))!=0)) apple <-c(apple,x[i])
}
return(apple)
}
```

To get results:
type:findPrime(num)
This is the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (x[i]%%(1:(x[i] - 1)) == 0) apple <- c(apple, x[i]) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

so how can I fix the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning message

Comment: Nor do i get prime numbers as output!

Comment: just type  warnings()  and you can see the warning message

Comment: `rm(list = ls())` and then try again. I think you are seeing a warning from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` statements only accept single elements and in your declaration seems to get the whole vector. I have rewritten your function using a `ifelse` expression wrapped inside a `sapply` loop.

I hope this works for you.

```
findPrime <- function(x = 0){

      primes <- c()

      # Prime finder
      primes <- sapply(X = x,FUN =  function(x) {
        ifelse(any(x %% (1:(x - 1)) != 0), T, F)}
        )

      # Select primes                 
      primes <- num[primes]

      return(primes)
    }

    findPrime(num)
```

I have checked another silly mistake... Inside the function change `num` for `x` in the select primes step and invert the `F`, `T` outcomes. It should look like this:

```
findPrime <- function(x = 0){

  primes <- c()

  # Prime finder
  primes <- sapply(X = x,FUN =  function(x) {
    ifelse(any(x %% (2:(x - 1)) == 0), F, T)}
  )

  # Select primes                 
  primes <- x[primes]

  return(primes)
}
```

I have just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answering but your code still return all the numbers in num not the Prime numbers I want, but I can't point out where the error is.

Comment: No need to vectorise `if` via *both* `ifelse` *and* `sapply`. Either is sufficient.

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you explain it in detail, please~ sorry I am a beginner. if I only you ifelse it seems that I still need to face the single element thing

Comment: I found the error. Aside the mistake defining the loop, your logic test compared all the numbers from 1 to x - 1. I am not a mathematician, but I think all numbers are divisible by 1. This is the corrected line.
`ifelse(any(x %% (2:(x - 1)) == 0), T, F)`

Answer (score -1):

use package "gmp" which has a function "isprime" which returns 0 for non prime numbers and 2 for prime numbers and then subset the data based on the same

say you have a vector a = c(1:10)

```
a = c(1:10)
b = gmp::isprime(a)
c = cbind(a,b)
c = as.data.frame(c)
c = c[c$b==2,]
a1 = c$a
a1
```

In your code: for(i in 1:n), there is the error

Comment: I think the questioner is more interested in why their code doesn't work than finding an efficient prime-finding function.

Comment: I have mentioned the error in the end of my ans too :)

Comment: @RahulKumarVij why is this error? You should explain that in more detail.

Comment: you are using a loop where you are giving only one value n but it should be a vector 1:10 something like this